# How to center a fullscreen image on page load using react-zoom-pan-pinch?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a page with a fullscreen image that can be panned from edge to edge. The page should load with the image centered on the page vertically and horizontally. I am using [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch) library for this purpose.  However, I'm facing an issue where the image is not centered on the page when it loads. Instead, it starts from the center and requires a click to center itself.

I've tried using the centerOnInit prop provided by the library, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Interestingly, when I replaced the image with a div, it centered perfectly on page load.

I have also experimented with CSS and referred to the library's documentation and examples, but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm missing or doing wrong.

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve the desired behavior of centering the fullscreen image on page load would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-brook-r45m75?file=/src/App.tsx).

App.tsx

```
export default function App() {
  const wrapperRef = createRef<ReactZoomPanPinchContentRef>();
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <TransformWrapper
        centerOnInit
        maxScale={5}
        disablePadding
        minScale={1.15}
        initialScale={1.15}
        ref={wrapperRef}
        pinch={{ disabled: true }}
        doubleClick={{ disabled: true }}
        wheel={{ disabled: true, touchPadDisabled: true }}
      >
        <TransformComponent wrapperClass="wrapper" contentClass="content">
          <img src={cat} alt="cat" className="cat-img" />
        </TransformComponent>
      </TransformWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.css

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  background: radial-gradient(#75c2c5, #5e99e7, #314687);
}

.container::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.25;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("./assets/waves.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cat-img {
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

EDIT: The issue is reproducible 100% of the time locally. But on the codesandbox it happens if you reload multiple times.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I assume it's a bug

Comment: Upon further investigation I noticed that it seems the top-left corner of the image is centered in the middle of the wrapper- which leads me to believe that the cause is that it centers the image before the src of the image has loaded. However I am unsure how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

After several frustrating attempts, I found a workaround for this that is entirely a hack. centerOnInit doesn't work. For some reason, only the top-left corner is centered.

I used the centerView handler provided in the docs and this moves the image to the center. However, I had to set the animationTime to 0 or else you'll be able to see the image actually moving towards the center on load.

```
  <TransformWrapper
      initialScale={1}
      centerZoomedOut={true}
      disablePadding={true}
      minScale={0.5}
      maxScale={7}
    >
      {({ centerView }) => (
        <div
          ref={transformWrapperRef}
          className="relative w-full h-full bg-gray-200 rounded-lg flex justify-center items-center "
          style={finalAppearance.finalBgColor}
        >
          {isLeftImageLoading || isRightImageLoading ? (
            <div className="absolute top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 mx-auto my-auto text-center w-36 h-36">
              <Loading />
              Loading Image
            </div>
          ) : null}

          <div
            style={{ position: "relative", width: wrapperDimensions.width, height: wrapperDimensions.height, }}
          >
            <TransformComponent
              wrapperStyle={{
                width: `${wrapperDimensions.width}px`,
                height: `${wrapperDimensions.height}px`,
              }}
            >
              <>
                {item.leftUri && (
                  <div id="leftImage" className="flex justify-end w-1/2">
                    <Image
                      src={item.leftUri}
                      className={`h-full w-auto ${isLeftImageLoading || isRightImageLoading
                        ? "opacity-0"
                        : "opacity-100"
                        }`}
                      style={{ maxHeight: `${wrapperDimensions.height}px`, maxWidth: `${wrapperDimensions.width / 2}px` }}
                      onLoad={() => {
                        setIsLeftImageLoading(false);
                        centerView(undefined, 0)
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
                {item.rightUri && (
                  <div id="rightImage" className="w-1/2">
                    <Image
                      src={item.rightUri}
                      className={`h-full w-auto ${isLeftImageLoading || isRightImageLoading
                        ? "opacity-0"
                        : "opacity-100"
                        }`}
                      style={{ maxHeight: `${wrapperDimensions.height}px`, maxWidth: `${wrapperDimensions.width / 2}px` }}
                      onLoad={() => {
                        setIsRightImageLoading(false);
                        centerView(undefined, 0)
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                )}
              </>
            </TransformComponent>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </TransformWrapper>
```